# Should we provide example questions in the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I am not sure how many of the new users read the FAQ, but for those that do a list of good questions that capture some of the best practices might help them make better questions themselves.

Do you think its a good idea to look through some of our highest-voted questions and list a few as examples of 'best-practice' in asking questions? Or would this simply not fit into the FAQ format?

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely one possibility. I'm noticing an increased number of new users who aren't quite asking the right questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, since I don't think it will help.

The site is full of questions and anyone who just reads a few questions will see the examples. We can collect them in a meta-post on best practices (and link to that meta post in "how to ask a good question" links part, but putting the examples in the FAQ will just make it unnecessarily longer and less likely to be read.

Our problem is not with users who read the FAQ, our problem is with users *who don't read the FAQ*.